# Add random variable after image url with javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, random, numbers

I have a page with an image on it, however this image changes quite frequently, but it has the same URL. To bypass the browser from caching an older version of the image, I want to add a random number variable after the URL. What is the best way to do this with Javascript?

So when the page loads, it does not load:

`http://test.com/image.png`

instead it loads:

`http://test.com/image.png?43673890`

So each time the page is reloads, it has a new variable so the latest version of the image is visible.

Comment: @sabithpocker Thanks, but how would I put it together? I'm still very new to Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your img tag an id, then you can

```
document.getElementById("imageid").src=document.getElementById("imageid").src + "?" + Math.random()* 100000000000000000000;
```

if the initial url has ? then do

```
document.getElementById("imageid").src=document.getElementById("imageid").src.split('?')[0] + "?" + Math.random()* 100000000000000000000;
```