# Update img src from a refreshed JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have a img src which just looks like this:

`<img [src]="currentImg" />`

Which traverses a JSON and grabs the image url.

I have a button underneath the image directly that refreshes the JSON feed.

```
<a (click)="refreshFeed(url)">Refresh feed</a>
```

```
  refreshFeed(url) {

    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.jsonService.getJson().subscribe(() => {
        this.currentImg = url.properties.img;
        return this.currentImg;
      })
    )
  }
```

However, while I can see it's fetching the new json, it doesn't seem to update the image url and change it's source at all, also, the image url will always be the same name in the json (img: "image.jpeg")

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Because you are assigning the same image from url that is passing as an argument

Comment: @corey, I agree with@Rahul's comment & I think there is something went wrong with Image URL. Please check that.

Comment: This is due to cache issue and hence this answer might help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54274128/7785337

Answer (score 1):

First, subscribe is a void function, there is no meaning for it to return a value.
Second, It seems like you're using a different Change Detection Strategy somewhere along the component tree.

Try doing the following, if it works then you definitely use the onPush strategy.

```
constructor(
    ...,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ...
) {
    ...
}

refreshFeed(url: string) {
    this.jsonService.getJson()
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.currentImg = data.properties.img;
            this.cd.detectChanges();
        })
}
```

I used the Rxjs "take" pipe instead of destroying subscriptions.
This is a better approach, try using it where you can.

I would not use any ngIfs. The image will jump every time the user generates a new image.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

.html

```
<img [src]="currentImg" *ngIf="showImage"/>
```

.ts

```
showImage:boolean

refreshFeed(url) {
    this.showImage = false;
    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.jsonService.getJson().subscribe(() => {
        this.currentImg = url.properties.img;
         this.showImage = true;
        return this.currentImg;
      })
    )
  }
```